# Stackful и Stackless coroutines

Tags: многопоточность, golang, coroutine

В чём различия двух типов корутин? И какой подход реализуется в Go? (каким типом являются горутины)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сравнивать горутины и корутины - это как сравнивать горячее с высоким. Они предназначены для разных задач и спроектированы по-разному.

Корутины в С++ задуманы для написания асинхронных алгоритмов и генераторов в виде функций. Корутины в С++ **возвращают значения**. Это принципиальное отличие от горутин. Всё в корутинах заточено на возвращение значений. `co_yield` и `co_return` создают значения, `co_await` получает значение. В каком-то смысле это старый недобрый `setjmp`/`longjmp` с поддержкой хранилища локальных переменных от компилятора.

Горутины предназначены для реализации легковесных потоков, для которых переключение не требует обращения к ядру. Горутины **не возвращают значения**. Соответственно, в го нет ни `yield`, ни `await`. Нужно явным образом организовывать передачу данных из горутины через каналы.

Я не буду разводить флейм на тему, что лучше - асинхронные алгоритмы с `yield`/`wait` или легковесные потоки с каналами. Лично я препочитаю потоки/горутины, потому что мне проще думать в стиле обмена данными между акторами, а не нарезки функциональности на асинхронную лапшу.

Возвращаясь к вашему вопросу - считайте горутины stackfull.